# Wireshark: configure for capturing ssl data

Tags: wireshark

I'm using Wireshark for getting all https packets and decoding them.

I follow two methods in Wireshark. The first method is on this link: [Wireshark SSL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL). In short, I do following things:

1. generate key.bem
2. Import to Wireshark in Protocols\SSL Section. I add an item in RSA Key List.

Here is the detail:

```
IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
Port: 0
Protocol: HTTP
Keyfile: point to by key.bem
Password: Empty
```

But When I tried to go some https page such as `https://www.google.com`. I still cannot decode.

Comment: The first issue I can see which needs correcting is the the protocol. You are using HTTP and SSL will use port 443, which is HTTPS.

Comment: @SleepyMan I have tried that before but not work. as I read, config port to 0 mean wireshark will try to decode data in all ports.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, protocol can only be HTTP or Data. But the port should be 443 for SSL/TLS.The Keyfile section should point to the private key. Do you have this? From my understanding, if you are going to google.com, google will have the private key and not you. So to test this, you will need to use something that you have control of in terms of keys/certificates.

Comment: @SleepyMan about private key, I maybe still don't know how it works. I just tried to generate a key.pem on my local computer.  As you said we have no way for getting https data.

Comment: Try and follow this link and I think you can achieve what you want. https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

Comment: @SleepyMan I have tried this link before. The problem with this is I have set up but no log file is written to SSLLOGFILE path.

Comment: If you're using libnss3, the feature has to be enabled at compile time which is not alway the case. See eg https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=842292

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Decoding HTTPS traffic to / from google will only work if you have the private key of Googles webserver imported into Wireshark and the connection is not using PFS (Perfect Forward Secrecy). Otherwise any form of TLS (SSL) encryption would be pretty useless.

For more Details on TLS/SSL see [Bulletproof SSL and TLS](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/bulletproof-ssl-and-tls/) by Ivan Ristić.

Comment: Apparently you can, using Firefox and Chrome by logging the symmetric session key used to encrypt TLS traffic to a file and feeding it into Wireshark to decrypt. Obviously only limitted to the traffic using the browser and not any other application. There is a guide on how to do this: https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

Comment: Following your argument, how could my browser decrypt traffic from google without knowing their private key?

Comment: "It turns out that Firefox and Chrome both support logging the symmetric session key used to encrypt TLS traffic to a file.  You can then point Wireshark at said file and presto! decrypted TLS traffic"

Comment: I'm researching about decode ssl packets using Wireshark. But I think decode SSL packets is doable. I can do similar thing on other apps such as Burp Suite by using proxy, and then providing faking cert.

Comment: @hqt: Sure. But then your not debugging the session between Client and Sever but between Client and Proxy.

Comment: @JeanPierre: Please try to learn the basics of public key encryption and TLS. I pointed to a very good reference in my answer.

Comment: I agree TLS would be useless if we could decrypt traffic between **anyone** and google without google private key.  But here, it's between **our browser** and google, so I find your statement confusing. Please try to read comments as honest attempts to improve the quality of everyone's understanding and the wording of the answers.